# Image to scroll across whole screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

Let's say I have a big image (mine is 3968x3584) and I want to view it zoomed in. OK, well I can usually zoom in and scroll using the scrollbars.

Well that's annoying. Is there a way I can take the image. And just start somewhere and have it "original" size and I can move it by doing the mouse "drag" across the screen.

and if you resize your browser screen, it will act accordingly.

Is there a jquery or such plugin that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this helps

http://code.google.com/p/panojs/

Here is a copy of what is written there so I can meet the 30 words this form is forcing me to do:

> PanoJS is an interactive JavaScript widget for panning and zooming a
>   panoramic image stitched together dynamically from smaller tiles. This
>   widget can be used for viewing images that are larger than the
>   available space in the browser viewport. Examples include maps or high
>   resolution document scans.